# How do I set and then unset environment variables while running a program?

Tags: environment-variables

Let's say I have a `program` that's dependent on some configuration by setting environment variables. Now I also don't want to pollute my local environment with 10 different environment variables, so I thought a script would be handy in this case:

```
set VAR1=...
set VAR2=...
.
.
# run the program
./program

unset VAR1
unset VAR2
.
.
```

So instead of running `./program` I would now be running this script. My question is, is this the idiomatic way of doing things? Are there better ways that I should know of?

Comment: What language is that? The syntax looks like that of `(t)csh`, but in `csh`, `set` sets shell variables, not environment variables (for which you need `setenv`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bourne-like or `rc`-like shells, to pass environment variables just to one invocation of one command, you'd do:

```
VAR1=value VAR2=other-value some-command with its args
```

Though note that in some shells, if `some-command` is a special builtin (such as `export`, `set`, `eval`) or a function, the variables remain set (though not always exported) afterwards.

The csh or tcsh shells have no equivalent though in those (or any shell for that matters), you can always use the `env` command:

```
env VAR1=value VAR2=other-value some-command with its args
```

You'll also want to use `env` in Bourne-like shells if you want to pass environment variables whose name is not a valid shell variable name (though using such variables is not recommended) such as:

```
env C++=/usr/bin/g++ some-command with its args
```

Note that in csh, `set var=value` sets a shell variable, not an environment variable for which you need `setenv var value`.

In the `fish` shell, you can use `set -lx` in a `begin...end` statement to limit the scope of the variable while still exporting it to the environment:

```
begin
  set -lx VAR1 value
  set -lx VAR2 other-value
  some-command with its args
end
```

You can do the same in `zsh` using an anonymous function:

```
(){
  local -x VAR1=value VAR2=other-value
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
}
```

Or:

```
function {
  local -x VAR1=value VAR2=other-value
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
}
```

Though you'd only prefer that over the standard `VAR1=value VAR2=other-value some-command with its args` syntax if there's more than one command you want to run in that environment.

In any Bourne-like shell, you can also limit the scope of variable assignments using a subshell:

```
(
  VAR1=value VAR2=other-value
  export VAR1 VAR2
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
)
```

POSIX shells (not the Bourne shell, though the Bourne shell is a thing of the past) can also do the assignment in the arguments to the `export` special builtin:

```
(
  export VAR1=value VAR2=other-value
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
)
```

That approach can also be used in `(t)csh`:

```
(
  setenv VAR1 value
  setenv VAR2 other-value
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
)
```

To run more than one command in an environment primed with variables whose name are not valid shell variable names, you can always have `env` start `zsh`, `bash`, `csh` or any other shell which doesn't strip those variables from the environment:

```
# most shell syntax:
env C++=/usr/bin/g++ zsh -c '
  some-command with its args
  some-other-command with other args
'
```

```
# (t)csh syntax
env C++=/usr/bin/g++ csh -c '\
  some-command with its args\
  some-other-command with other args\
'
```

Also beware that `unset`ting a variable (which you do with `unset var` in (t)csh and most Bourne-like shells, `unset -v var` in `bash`, `var = ()` in `rc`-like shells, `set -e var` in `fish`) is not the same as restoring the old variable value. After all the example codes above, the variables end up being unset only if they were initially unset.

Answer (score 0):

If running the program is the last thing you do in the script, i.e. you don't need to worry about "polluting" the environment for the rest of the duration of the script, there is no need to unset the variables. Exporting an environment variable only affects the current process and their children; you can't change the environment of the parent process. When the script exits, the variables are gone.

Btw, you need to use `export` to export the variables into the environment, `set` only sets them locally in the shell.

Comment: In the shells that have an `export` special builtin command, the `set` special builtin sets options, positional parameters and with ksh array variables (with `set -A var val1 val2`), but not scalar variables with `set var=value` syntax.

Comment: Yes, and? Do variables created with the `set` special builtin in these shells affect the environment of child processes in any way, i.e. does the shell mark these for passing via the `envp` argument to the program? Do any shells *without* an `export` builtin (e.g. csh, tcsh) pass variables set with `set` in the environment? I don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: My point is that `export` is likely  gonna be of no use to the OP as they're apparently not using a Bourne-like shell.